# how to set the value of the column in a select statement in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

how to change the output value of the column and it's column name if a certain condition was met?
let's say i have table A, it has 3 columns
id,salutation, name, surname,gender

i can select all of those by

```
select * from A
```

so what if I want to output the value of salutation based from what gender the data row is,
how to do that in select statement, the pseudo code is like this

```
select everything, if the gender is Male, then set salutation to Mr. else, set salutation to Ms. but then change the salutation into alias namePrefix
```

how to do that in pure select statement in oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CASE` statement seems to be what you need. You can do something like this:

```
select yourtable.*,
case when gender = 'Male' then 'Mr. ' || name else 'Ms. ' || name end as namePrefix
from yourtable
```

The `CASE` statement will help you generate the computed column `namePrefix` for each row in your table such that either `Mr.` or `Ms.` is prefixed based on the value for `gender` column in that row.

Comment: The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` not `+`

Comment: We are in a Oracle Database so we can use DECODE too."Decode(gender,'Male','Mr.','Ms.')||name as namePrefix". It all comes down to preference.